# MySQL How to get the row with max date when joining multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My goal is the get a list of current prices and prices at the time of whatever date is given. The price as of today is always product.price. Each time a new price is set, an entry is added to product_audit and revinfo.

If we are looking for what the prices were on 2020-11-31, it would return:

```
num      CurrentPrice      OldPrice
--------------------------------------
1001     100               175
1030     110               100
2010     150               130
```

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:** My intention is to get what the price was on a specific day. So OldPrice is actually the newest entry in Product_aud/revinfo that is before or on the set date (in this case, 2020-11-31). Looking specifically at code 1001, the price was changed on 2020-08-02, 2020-09-26, and 2020-01-08. If we are looking at 2020-11-31, that means it should grab 2020-09-26 because it is the soonest date before then. This means the price of 1001 on 2020-11-31 was 175.

There are three tables: Product, product_audit, revinfo

Everytime the price is changed, an entry is added to product_audit with the new price and a reference to a new entry in revinfo that has the date/time. Revinfo contains entries for other audit tables mixed in.

product.id = product_audit.id

product_audit.rev = revinfo.id

**product**

```
id     num      price
------------------------
1      1001     100
2      1030     110
3      2010     150
```

**product_audit**

```
id     rev      price
------------------------
1      1        200
1      3        175     
1      6        100
2      2        100
2      7        110
3      4        130
3      5        120
3      8        150
```

**revinfo**

```
id     timestamp
-------------------
1      2020-08-02
2      2020-09-25
3      2020-09-26
4      2020-11-12
5      2020-12-20
6      2021-01-08
7      2021-01-09
8      2021-01-23
```

Of course this just returns the oldest price from product_audit:

```
SELECT product.num, product.price AS CurrentPrice, product_audit.price AS OldPrice

FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_audit ON product_audit.id = product.id
LEFT JOIN revinfo ON revinfo.id = product_audit.rev

WHERE rev.timestamp <= "2020-11-31"
GROUP BY product.id
```

I tried nesting joins like this based on some stuff I was reading, but quickly realized it still wasn't going to get the right price:

```
SELECT product.id, product.num, product.price AS CurrentPrice, revisions.price AS OldPrice

FROM product
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_audit.id AS id, product_audit.price AS price, MAX(revinfo.timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM product_audit
    LEFT JOIN revinfo ON product_audit.rev = revinfo.id
    WHERE revinfo.timestamp <= $DATE{Date}
    GROUP BY product_aud.id) AS revisions ON revisions.id = product.id
```

I can't seem to think of how to get to that last step. Some sort of WHERE timestamp = (SELECT...) maybe? But I haven't been able to figure that out.

Also, just a heads up, I'm limited to statements that start with SELECT because of permissions. I can't add functions or anything like that.

Comment: Do your SQL queries run? they appear to have syntax errors (space in column alias, group by is missing columns or you are missing aggregate functions)

Comment: @Akina here is a fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fbvrgo2gRLoBPhgwQnuvY9/0

Comment: *Assume we are looking for prices on 2020-11-31, it would return* For product 1001 the price of 100 is set at `2021-01-08`, i.e. after `2020-11-31`... how can it be "current"??

Comment: @Aron Fixed the column alias. It does run otherwise though. Thanks for setting up the fiddle for me! I should have put something on there. Sorry. First time posting.

Comment: @Akina The "current" price is whatever the price was last set to and is stored in the latest entry of product_audit and in the price column for product. I meant it to be the actively used price. It's just to compare with whatever the price used to be.

Comment: *Assume we are looking for prices on 2020-11-31*  November 31 - not exists...

Comment: @Akina I edited the question to hopefully be more clear. I'm looking at your and Aron's answers now

Answer (score 0):

I had to assume how we were getting the "old" price, and my assumption was that you wanted the "earliest" revision record, so I used Row_number and a derived table to get that record and then use it in the join constraint for the revision table... not exactly sure what your logic is, but here is a fiddle with the resultset that matches your "desired results"

```
SELECT product.num, product.price AS CurrentPrice, product_audit.price AS OldPrice

FROM product
LEFT JOIN (select p.price, p.id, p.rev,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.id order by p.rev asc) as rn
           From product_audit p
           
          ) AS product_audit ON product_audit.id = product.id
            and product_audit.rn = 1

LEFT JOIN revinfo ON revinfo.id = product_audit.rev
WHERE revinfo.timestamp <= '2020-11-31';
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fbvrgo2gRLoBPhgwQnuvY9/3

Comment: Why LEFT joining? the task assumes that non-existent data not needed, so INNER JOIN must be enough.

Comment: yea true. left join is just left over from playing with the query. this is implicitly an inner join anyway since we are joining revinfo and have a constraint in the where clause. hopefully the poster can clean up the code to suit their needs

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'm looking for the NEWEST price before or on the set date. I'll try to clarify that better in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT product.num,
                     product.price CurrentPrice,
                     product_audit.price OldPrice,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product.num 
                                        ORDER BY revinfo.`timestamp` DESC) rn
              FROM product
              JOIN product_audit ON product_audit.id = product.id
              JOIN revinfo ON revinfo.id = product_audit.rev 
              WHERE revinfo.`timestamp` <= @date 
              )
SELECT num, CurrentPrice, OldPrice
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a276ec8ad89e3c2f3aaeee411072fa3e